# Problem with upgrading to libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb

Tags: 16.04

libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb got released on 28th Jun 2018 (yesterday), while its installation throws error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -D=3 -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
D000001: ensure_statoverrides: new, (re)loading
(Reading database ... 25657 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb ...
D000001: process_archive oldversionstatus=installed
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:amd64.prerm ( upgrade 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 )
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
D000002: maintscript_new nonexistent preinst '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst'
Unpacking libstdc++6:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) over (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb (--install):
unable to create '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21'):     Permission denied
D000002: maintscript_new nonexistent postrm '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++6:amd64.postinst ( abort-upgrade 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 )
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.postinst ( triggered ldconfig )
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
```

This is happening on a LXD container:

```
$ sudo lxc launch ubuntu:xenial myMachine
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just if someone else would hit this, dropping container and re-creating it from a scratch solved this.